# Create reusable functional component in flutter

Tags: api, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sliver

I want to create a reusable service component in a flutter, In react-native, we can achieve this by belove code.

```
export async function Service({
  api,
  third_party,
  method,
  params
}) {
  const headers = {};

  set(headers, 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  set(headers, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');

  const reqBody = {
    method,
    headers,
    timeout: 30 * 1000
  };

  if (!isEmpty(params)) {
    reqBody.body = JSON.stringify(params);
  }

  return fetch(path, reqBody)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('response json data = ', data);
      if (data.errors) {
          if (data.code === 403 && data.number === 1006) {
            emitter.emit('AppRoot:VERSION_UPDATED', data.links);
          }
          return {
            result: 'error',
            ...data
          };
      }
      return {
        result: 'ok',
        ...data
      };
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return {
        result: 'error',
        message: 'Please check your internet connection!'
      };
    });
}
```

Use of Service component.

```
OpenMed_Service,
{
    api: 'patients/add-to-account',
    method: 'POST',
    params: payload
}
```

Service.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class Service extends StatelessWidget {
  final String api;
  final String method;
  var params;

  Service({
    this.api,
    this.method,
    this.params
  });

  var headers = {};
  final String url = "http://www.adminapi/somee.com/";
  var reqBody = {
    'header': ('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
    timeout: 30 * 1000
  };

  if (!isEmpty(params)) {
    reqBody.body = json.decode(params);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(method == 'post') {
      Future<http.Response> createPost(Post post) async{
        final response = await http.post('$url',
        headers: reqBody.headers,
        body: json.encode(post));
        return json.decode(response.body);
      }
    } else if(method == 'get') {
      Future<http.Response> getPost() async{
        final response = await http.get('$url/$api');
        return postFromJson(response.body);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to create statlessWidgets but get lots of error. I have created service class it needs to return widget but I want' to return JSON data.

Anyone know how can I archive the same thing in the flutter.

Comment: "but get lots of error." Would be better you post the code that demonstrates what you tried and what error you got.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have added my service.dart code please check and give me solution for this.

Comment: What does "functional widget" mean in this context? Is it a widget that provides some non UI feature? I'd suggest to do such stuff entirely outside of the widget tree. "Everything is a widget" is kind of a mantra for Flutter, but I don't see the point in business logic or network access being implemented in a widget - rather the opposite.

Comment: There is still no information about what "lots of error" is about.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer "What does "functional widget" mean in this context? Is it a widget that provides some non-UI feature?" - No, It does not return any UI, I didn't any idea about how to achieve RN functional component in Flutter, so I have tried by my self. Can you please do sample code in a flutter for creating reusable service component. Thanks, Gunter for your help.

Comment: How I can create Service Class without Widget

Comment: Just create a normal class. Use InherotedWidget to make it available to widgets.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you do a sample code. I am still didn't get what you try to say. Can you please add sample code for the service class.InherotedWidget check data was change or not.